# Latency access times for L1 cache

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, cpu

At this web link:

http://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/IvyBridge.html

it says the latency for Ivy Bridge L1 cache access is:

> - L1 Data Cache Latency = 4 cycles for simple access via pointer
> - L1 Data Cache Latency = 5 cycles for access with complex address calculation (size_t n, *p; n = p[n]).

Instead of "simple", did they mean if the pointer size is the same as the word size? So if the pointer is 32-bit and its a 32-bit OS then this would be "simple", otherwise it would cost the "complex" latency?

I just don't quite understand their explanation for the difference in the two latencies.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious: *p is four cycles, p [n] is five cycles.

Comment: @gnasher729 and what has "size_t n" got to do with "*p is four cycles, p [n] is five cycles" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full x86 effective address looks like `displacement + base + index * scale` (where `displacement` is a constant, `base` and `index` are registers, and `scale` is 1, 2, 4 or 8).

It sounds like they call an address simple if only the `displacement` is present (or maybe additionally the  `base` term), while having `index * scale` would certainly fall under the complex category.

**Update**: Indeed, the intel optimization manual has this statement (for Sandy Bridge, though): *The common load latency is five cycles. When using a simple addressing mode, base plus offset that is
smaller than 2048, the load latency can be four cycles*. See also Table 2-12. *Effect of Addressing Modes on Load Latency*.

Comment: And the addressing can be even more complex if the segment base is non-zero. Non-zero segment bases are still used in x86-64 (e.g., to provide a Thread Local Storage pointer).

Comment: Would you be able to direct your answer in terms of C programming constructs? When would displacement, base, index and scale not/feature etc?