# Difference between memory fetch with and without offset on Intel

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Appel explains in "[Runtime Tags Aren't Necessary](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/142.ps)" on page 8 how to distinguish integers from pointers by tagging pointers:

> Some implementations use a low-order tag of 0 for integers, then integer
>   addition can then be done with the ordinary machine add instruction, and no
>   shifting or correction will be necessary (since 2x + 2y = 2(x + y)). This requires that pointers have a tag of 1; but pointer-fetches can be done with odd offsets to compensate.

The idea is: if a pointer is aligned, the value is a multiple of 2 or 4. And in that case the lower 1 or 2 bits are always zero and can be set to some value to implement a tagging to distinguish integers from pointers.

An untagged pointer fetch without offset in Intel syntax is:

```
mov    eax, DWORD PTR [ebx]
```

And the equivalent tagged pointer fetch with offset is this:

```
mov    eax, DWORD PTR [ebx-0x1]
```

What is the difference in cycles for the two fetches?

Comment: fetch usually means fetching the next batch of instructions and a sane processor at this level would do that aligned and in multiples of bus sized chunks.   Unaligned accesses, can cause at best an extra clock on top of the overhead because you have to do that extra data cycle to get that extra item (well at best sometimes the data can be shifted depends on the bus architecture).  But could also push you into a complete separate bus cycle depends on the bus. say it is 32 bits wide (not relevant to if the processor is 32 or 64) and you do an aligned 64 bit operation...

Comment: that ideally results in one transfer with a length of 2, but if you make that unaligned you may end up with three transfers, the first fraction, a whole 32 bit transfer, and the latter fraction.  Depends on the architecture.  at a handful or more clocks per transfer that gets very costly very fast.

Comment: too broad to determine exact cycle counts, there are too many factors for a single answer.  there are also cache effects if you wander across a cache line boundary.

Comment: and I assume when you say intel you mean x86

Comment: @old_timer I do not talk about unaligned memory access. The memory access in my example is aligned. And the overhead for the offset does not depend on the cache, because the value is an immediate argument.

Comment: If you says so...you are accessing two different addresses that are offset by one byte.  use whatever terms you like, if they are both aligned as you say then what is the difference?  and the what is your actual question, if they are the same everything then why would the cycle counts differ?

Comment: or is your question related to the size of the instruction and the difference in the size of the instruction?

Comment: the instruction is one byte longer 4 instead of 3 so that is 33% more fetch time.  compared to the unaligned access cost, somewhat irrelevant, a cost but not your primary cost.

Comment: You can't really count cycles on modern processors as they are super scalar. Look at Agner Fog's tables for performance details. Typically, a SIB byte has a slight performance penalty which depends on a lot of external factors.

Comment: @fuz You mean the table on page 10? Which line in the table describes the move with offset from my example?

Comment: I haven't been able to measure any difference (on Haswell), but I'm getting a latency of 5 for both and it's usually reported to be lower so this may be a measurement error. Well either way, Agner's tables usually say "all addressing modes" for loads and stores.

Comment: @harold So this means: practically there is no difference?

Comment: agreed, the extra byte is virtually undetectable, certainly not if you are running with an operating system, etc.  the real if any cost is your cache line is one byte shorter, a single byte can make between no difference to a huge difference depending on the context, if based on evictions and the rate at which the code at that boundary is used, it could (a small loop that this one byte now spread across a boundary).

Comment: @old_timer I think you still talk about something different. I am asking about the time to execute the memory fetch, not the time to fetch the instruction.

Comment: one could craft a benchmark that makes it noticeable and one could craft a benchmark that virtually doesnt (demonstrates the lack of value of benchmarks), if you are running a sim and looking inside the processor clearly there is a difference, subtle and may be isolated, prefetching and pipelining likely swallows the 4 vs 3 difference assuming all other factors are held constant.

Comment: memory fetch is an instruction fetch, the execution of the instruction is now unaligned, and that is measurable if done right, which are you asking about, the time it takes to read the 3 vs 4 byte instruction from memory, or the time it takes to read a 32 bit value from ram and put it in eax?

Comment: both have an effect, most folks will not be able to see it but again it can be seen at the right level or can be used to cause a noticeable effect, which are you looking for.

Comment: I already covered both cases, the time it takes to fetch the instructions and the time it takes to do the load.

Comment: If you feel you need a book that explains this then read Zen of assembly language, you can make a pdf/epub of it from github.  It sets the mindset needed to understand how to look for these differences and then you extend that into demonstrating the no effect and the with effect...

Comment: I don't understand the critics on this question. It's very well posed, it's clear and self-contained. I also believe that Harold answered it; by adding a note about the extra byte for the offset loads/stores and the fact that this kind of loads/stores is very frequent when working with pointers, one gets a complete answer.

Comment: The time to "execute" the memory fetch is the same for both instructions because the perform the exact same memory fetch operation. It's the time to fetch the instruction, decode the instruction and calculate the address to fetch that might be be different. BeeOnRope's answer suggests the one or both of the last factors can make a 1 cycle difference in latency, though usually not in this case. However the increase in code size, not just of one byte, but one byte for every pointer access like this, will hurt performance because it will push code out of the L1 cache faster.

Comment: @RossRidge - I think you are really splitting hairs on terminology there. The OP ultimately asks _What is the difference in cycles for the two fetches?_ - I think it's clear that they don't want to somehow separate out the address generation from the "memory" fetch part of the timing. Indeed, most accesses are satisfied by cache, so perhaps they don't "fetch from memory" at all (if you interpret that as DRAM access). I think the simplest and charitable interpretation of the question is "how long will this take" and most users could care less the breakdown between agen and actual access.

Comment: ... and the breakdown is anyway platform specific, often hidden or uncertain, etc. I agree with your other points, and will update my answer to reflect them.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - it's pretty simple (and frustrating): there seem to be a handful of users who hate any kind of "how long will this take" questions (especially if tagged `c` or `c++`) since _In general that can't be known!_ or _It's platform specific!_ or _The standard doesn't cover runtime!_ or _Insert terminology quibble here_ or _It depends on XYZ_, or (my least favorite) _Modern CPUs are too complex and unknowable to model!_  Of course, despite all that, it is often possible to give a reasonable answer while mentioning the caveats...

Comment: @BeeOnRope It's not at all clear to me what the original poster is asking. The fact that he said "I am asking about the time to execute the memory fetch, not the time to fetch the instruction", the comment I was responding to, suggests he's not actually asking how "long will this take". But I don't think he understands what it is he's asking, so that's why I (simplistically) separated out the relevant factors that do affect how long it will take so he could maybe understand that his question isn't entirely clear and hopefully improve it.

Comment: @RossRidge that part was clear (to me) from the comment thread leading up to it. old_timer was pointing out issues that might cause the instruction fetch to be slower due to the extra byte, and the OP is subsequently saying "ignore that part and just concentrate on the execution of the instruction". It was clear enough. Often you know the ifetch + decoding isn't going to play a measurable role because a long loop comes from the uop cache, for example, or you just know you have fetch and icache to spare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity of the addressing mode generally has no impact on the *throughput* of load instructions, but it may have an impact of 1 cycle on the *latency*<sup>1</sup>.

In particular, a *simple* addressing mode, which is `[base]` or `[base + offset]` where `offset < 2048` usually takes 4 cycles, while complex modes (that's anything that isn't simple) take 5 cycles. That's for loads into general purpose registers: for vector loads you usually add 1 or 2 more cycles.

So in your case, you are using only `base` with a very small offset, so you should get the fastest load latency of 4 cycles.

This applies to Intel, I'm not sure about AMD.

Details are in the Intel optimization guide, but here's [the source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22869222/149138) I could find most quickly.

As Ross mentions in the comments, there is at least one more minor downside to using the offset: the instruction is [one byte longer](https://godbolt.org/g/tGahI9) for the version with an offset (and would be 4 bytes longer if your offset is outside the range -128 to 127), which slightly increases pressure on the icache.

---

<sup>1</sup> It goes without saying that this is for hits in L1. If you miss L1, latency will be longer - perhaps *much* longer and it probably doesn't matter if you still pay an extra cycle in that case (but I suppose you do, on average, since the miss doesn't get started until the address is calculated).